bitbake devtool failed with with error: Layer workspacelayer is not compatible
After I update my project layers from kirkstone to nanbield.
The devtool can't work anymore. the following error print show everytime when I try to run the devtool
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
ERROR: Layer workspacelayer is not compatible with the core layer which only supports these series: nanbield (layer is compatible with ${LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_core})
ERROR: Layer workspacelayer is not compatible with the core layer which only supports these series: nanbield (layer is compatible with ${LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_core})

Anyone have magic to fix this?

have you commited changes ?

Yes, the the commit was changed and the commit id is also updated. I guess this is related the layer.conf parameter in workspace folder.

do not remove kirkstone, just let it and add nanbield

I'm temporary workaround this trouble by:
Change the following line in file build/workspace/conf/layer.conf:
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_workspacelayer = "${LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_core}"

to
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_workspacelayer = "kirkstone nanbield"

